# Excel Data validation list from single cell

Tags: excel

I would like to create in a single cell a list to use for data validation.

For example:

Single cell:

```
| 1-3,6,8 |
```

Data validation list:

```
1

2

3

6

8
```

Comment: can you clarify please, you have in one cell, say `B1`, value `| 1-3,6,8 |`, and then, using `B1` you need to create dropdown for another cell, say `A1`?

Comment: if you assign a data validation from a list of values to a specific cell, when that specific cell is selected a dropdown list is shown with the possible values selected before.
instead of a list from a range of cells i would like to create that same list but from a single cell with the value, for example, 1-3,6,8 that would create a list containing the values 1,2,3,6,8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can try this:

```
Sub DataVal()
    Dim x As String, v, v1, i As Integer, j As Integer, s As String
    x = Range("C1")
    v = Split(x, ",")
    For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
       If InStr(v(i), "-") <> 0 Then
          v1 = Split(v(i), "-")
          For j = v1(LBound(v1)) To v1(UBound(v1))
             s = s & j & ","
          Next
       Else
          s = s & v(i) & ","
       End If
    Next
    s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
    With Range("D1").Validation
       .Delete
       .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=s
    End With
End Sub
```

I assume you want to apply data validation to `D1` cell and get the values for that data validation in `C1`, change at will

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom VBA function.  Very pseudo-code follows:

```
function validateCell(strValues as string, rngValid as range) as boolean
  validateCell = true 'will return true unless the following loop finds an invalid value
  for each value in strValues 'this will require some parsing of strValues parameter
    if value is not in rngValid 
      then validateCells = False
      exit function
    end if
  next value
end function
```

Comment: this code you gave me, will only validate the value, I'm sorry i didn't explained myself correctly, what i would like is not only to validate but also create a dropdown list when the cell is clicked with the only possible values. is that possible?

Comment: Ohhhh I get it. You want to put 1-3,6,8 in a single cell to use as the validation list?  Write a function that loops from 1 to <max> value, and parses your input cell.  Stick the values that belong into your validation range.  If all the input cells use the same rule, you're golden.